# Can XML-RPC methods be called by name (as strings) in Python?

Tags: python, call, xml-rpc, getattr, xmlrpclib

In python, calling XML-RPC methods involves invoking methods on a proxy object:

```
from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy
print ServerProxy('https://example.com/rpc').api.hello_there('John')
```

In some other languages, like perl, you pass your method name as a method parameter.

```
use Frontier::Client;
$p = Frontier::Client->new(url => 'https://example.com/rpc');
$result = $p->call('api.hello_there', 'John');
print $result;
```

Is there a way to invoke XML-RPC methods by name, as strings, in Python?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `getattr`, as with any Python object.

```
func = getattr(ServerProxy('https://example.com/rpc'), "api.hello_there")
print func('John')
```

Comment: You can't use getattr with dotted names; think you'd need getattr(getattr(..., 'api'), 'hello_there').

Comment: Maybe it works in this particular case; it doesn't work with Python objects in general (the "as with any Python object" part of your answer).

Comment: I think that this wouldn't work in general, but xmlrpclib.ServerProxy overrides __getattr__ in a way that makes this work correctly. Thanks!